# Microsoft VBA on Linux

Tags: wine, libreoffice, microsoft-office

I really, really want to switch to Linux as my everyday OS. However, one of the things I must be able to do for my job is write / fix VBA macros for Excel.

I know LibreOffice has it's own scripting language.. but from the [documentation](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Using_Microsoft_Office_and):

> With a few exceptions, Microsoft Office and LibreOffice cannot run the same macro code. Microsoft Office uses VBA (Visual Basic for Applications) code, and LibreOffice uses Basic code based on the LibreOffice API (Application Program Interface) environment. Although the programming language is the same, the objects and methods are different.

I suppose one option would be to run real Excel in Wine? Are there any other options?

Comment: Do you have copies of all the software you will be using?  I recommend using a virtualization platform, for example [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) using Ubuntu as the host, and Windows as the guest.  Install Office inside the Windows Guest.  I've done this with a VB6 legacy program

Comment: @ECarterYoung This is for my personal machine, part of the point is that I don't want to buy a Windows or an Excel license

Comment: Whether you use Wine or VirtualBox you will need the Install CD, of at least Office in order to set either way up, and if you use VirtualBox you will need an OS copy.  Wine works better with the native Office DLL's also.  Hint: If you have a computer with a restore set, use the Serial number inside the VirtualBox.  I will say nothing more, except to say that this is legal because you own the PC.

Comment: You might be able to use office online, at https://office.com/start/default.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I use `VirtualBox` VMs for Windows 10 obtained from here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/virtual-machines

You can try out Microsoft Office for 30 days here: https://products.office.com/en-us/try

This maynot be a long term solution, as the trial will expire. Unless you have scripted the setup of the VM/Office, it will be pretty tedious to set it up every time.